# How to convert the result into fractions

Tags: python, numpy, decimal, equation, fractions

I would like to have results in a form  e.g. x= 3/8, y = 1/2

```
import random
import numpy as np

a = random.randint(2,10)
b = random.randint(2,10)
c = random.randint(2,10)
d = random.randint(2,10)
e = random.randint(2,10)
f = random.randint(2,10)

print('{}x + {}y = {}'.format(a,b,c))
print('{}x - {}y = {}'.format(d,e,f))

A = np.array([ [a,b], [d,e] ])
b = np.array([c,f])
z = np.linalg.solve(A,b)

print(z)
```

Comment: For symbolic math you should use [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) instead of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I have used sympy and this code seems to work well:

import random

from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

x, y = symbols('x y')

a = random.randint(2,10)

b = random.randint(2,10)

c = random.randint(2,10)

d = random.randint(2,10)

e = random.randint(2,10)

f = random.randint(2,10)

print('{}x + {}y = {}'.format(a,b,c))

print('{}x - {}y = {}'.format(d,e,f))

eq1 = Eq(a*x + b*y - c)

eq2 = Eq(d*x - e*y - f)

sol = solve((eq1, eq2),(x, y))

print(sol)

Output:6x + 6y = 6

4x - 5y = 6

{x: 11/9, y: -2/9}